camera not working using Quagga.js in odoo 11
I am working on a web application create module that requires access to the camera. The application is served over HTTPS using Nginx, as browsers typically mandate HTTPS for accessing hardware like cameras. However, I am encountering an issue where the camera cannot be accessed, even though HTTPS is properly configured.
Here’s the configuration of my Nginx .conf file:
server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  localhost;

    ssl_certificate      D:\certificate\cpanel.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  D:\certificate\cpanel.key;
    
    # log
    access_log D:\\master\\nginx-1.26.2\\logs\\odoo.access.log;
    error_log D:\\master\\nginx-1.26.2\\logs\\odoo.error.log;

    # Redirect requests to odoo backend server
    proxy_read_timeout 720s;
    proxy_connect_timeout 720s;
    proxy_send_timeout 720s;

    # Add Headers for odoo proxy mode
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

    # common gzip
    gzip_types text/css text/less text/plain text/xml application/xml application/json application/javascript;
    gzip on;

    client_body_in_file_only clean;
    client_body_buffer_size 32K;
    client_max_body_size 500M;
    sendfile on;
    send_timeout 600s;
    keepalive_timeout 300;
    
    location / {
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8069;
    }
    
    # Cache static files
    
#    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
#    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

#    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
#    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

#    location / {
#        root   html;
#        index  index.html index.htm;
#    }
}


